# xml file not loaded while using ApplicationContext

Tags: java, xml

I am using application context to read the xml file in my java class.But the proper xml file is not loading.Please help me.I am missing something here.

P:S It is also not throwing filenotfound error for the xml file that is not present.The line is just getting executed and the control moves to next line

```
ApplicationContext appContext = null;
appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/ayifos.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ayifos.xml");
```

this will work if your `ayifos.xml` file in **src** folder only for standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you point to the classpath as a place (**classpath***:/ayifos.xml),
directory where your ayifos.xml is, must be in JVM classpath when JVM starts. Either in system variable classpath or in java command line -cp parameter.

P.S. of course if your app packaged into jar and runs from there, ayifos.xml can be inside the jar. Actually, it is main purpose for addresses like classpath*: